# Is it possible to get Rubygems working with Ruby 1.8.3?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, http-status-code-302

I need to get Rubygems working with Ruby 1.8.3.

I know there are old versions of Rubygems which work with that version, and think Rubygems 1.0.1 was the last.

I can install it but when I try to install a gem I get the following error:

```
http response 302 fetching ...
```

Does someone know any tips to get it working except update my Ruby version?

Answer (score 3):

The 302 response is the Internet's way of telling you you're going to be redirected to a different URL.

I suspect that error is the result of being redirected to a site that no longer exists. In your home directory there might be a file called `.gemrc`. `cat ~/.gemrc` and you should see some information like:

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

The `:sources:` key is the... uh... key. `https://rubygems.org` is the current repo for gems. Your (old) version of Rubygems probably doesn't know that.

---

That said, it'd be REALLY smart to update your Ruby if at all possible. Installing gems with a Ruby that old will be a problem, plus you are missing a myriad of security patches and bug fixes. If you are not able use `sudo` to install on your system, then give serious consideration to using RVM or RBEnv to install a more current version in your home directory as a sandbox. Your code, your sanity, and your system, will thank you.

Comment: Running older versions of Rails is not possible any more, and Ruby 1.8.3 doesn't support the later safe versions of Rails. There are [automatic exploits](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5776422) out in the wild and your site will be crawled eventually by one of them. Test your apps with a tool like [Gem Canary](http://gemcanary.com/) to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: I just checked both rbenv and rvm, and neither support installing Ruby < 1.8.6. rbenv installs 1.8.6-p383, and RVM installs 1.8.6-p420.

Comment: At this point you'd probably have to build from source, and I'd only recommend doing this if you're an archaeologist.

Comment: I've tested with your sources and now I get : 
`http error 400 fetching rubygems.org/yaml ` 
I don't know if it's normal to get "/yaml" after the URL. 
It doesn't disturb me if I have to build it from source.. will try that if I can't find any other fastest solutions.

Comment: Ok, it's work with rubygems 1.2.0 , probably with other "more updated" version too. When installing it tells you that you need ruby > 1.8.3 but you can edit setup.rb, and change this value, then it install.
After when you try to get for example `gem -v` it will tell you the same error .. :
edit `/usr/local/bin/gem ` and change the restriction too.